# UWP apps: Blank icons in start menu

Tags: windows-10, icons, start-menu, uwp

All of my UWP app icons are blank/empty/missing in the start menu search only. They appear correct in the start menu list itself, in settings. Some are missing in the taskbar as well, some are not.

[image: comparison]

I am using sagethumbs for some file extensions, but I disabled it and the issue persisted (after restarting Windows Explorer). I cleared the icon cache, still no luck.

Anyone know a fix for this?

I am using Windows 10 (1803 - Build 17134.112)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT thanks for your reply. I followed the steps given in the answer of your linked discussion but it didn't change anything. The icons already were generated in windows explorer, but still don't render in the start menu search. Maybe I just installed to much Windows "enhancing" software such as SageThumbs and MediaPreview that aren't officially supported for Windows 10.

Comment: @Run5k I read the answers to the linked post prior to writing this question and tried some but they didn't help. Now read it again and tried toggling the resolution as described and it fixed the issue. A really weird bug..

Comment: SOLUTION: change the scaling & resolution and return it back. Thanks a lot FELIX!!! Your comment saved me, though I see at in the last minute when I've tried almost everything and lost hope.